# fix time duration values minutes:seconds in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a boxscore data set of a basketball team with mm:ss played (ex. 44:46) when I uploaded the csv to the table the values whose greater than 24 somehow became hh:mm (ex. 44:46 became 44:46:00) while the others just stayed the same (ex. 5:04), it is currently saved as a `varchar` data type.

How do I fix it so I can use the values to get for example the player with the highest time played in the team or the average time played for each player?

Comment: You should have stored those values in  a column defined as `interval`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name should i edit the values first to add '00:' at the start of the values then uploadd as interval data type?

Comment: Not necessary. `44:46` will be converted to a correct `interval`. But `44:46` is the same `interval` as `44:46:00` (44 hours, 46 minutes, 0 seconds)

Comment: But in order to answer this properly, please show us the SQL query you are using to select the values. Postgres will most certainly not change a `varchar` value that way. So it was either done by the tool you used to import the data or it is done by the tool you use to display/select those values.

Comment: so 44:46 as interval when uploaded to a table will be saved as 44 hours 46 minutes and 0 seconds? but it should only be 44 minutes 46 seconds, i can just create another table with the correct 'minutes' column as interval but how do i make sure it is saved as 00:44:46?

Comment: So what code/query converts your varchar value to the representation `44:46:00`

Comment: i just checked, it is from an excel file saved as 44:46 no format then saved as a csv, now inside csv the values changed (44:46 to 1/1/1900  8:46:00 PM displayed as 44:46:00) -- (5:04 to 5:04:00 AM displayed as 5:04) -- (0:00 to 12:00:00 AM displayed as 0:00) i havent actually made any queries yet since im sure the values in the table are incorrectly stored

Comment: Well, then it's Excel that messes up the values, not Postgres. It seems Excel treats those values as a `time` value, not a duration.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH formatted_time AS (
    SELECT 
        player, 
        CAST(SUBSTRING(time_played, 1, 2) AS INT) * 60 + CAST(SUBSTRING(time_played, 4, 2) AS INT) AS time_in_seconds
    FROM 
        your_table
)
SELECT 
    player, 
    time_in_seconds, 
    time_in_seconds / 60 || ':' || time_in_seconds % 60 AS time_played_formatted
FROM 
    formatted_time
```

Comment: replaced time_played, player with my column name and your_table with my table and got  *ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "0:"
SQL state: 22P02*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```sql
/*input*/
create table tab1( interval varchar(100));
insert into tab1 values( '44:46:00' );
insert into tab1 values( '5:04' );
/*Query*/  
select case when charindex(':',interval,4) = 0 then interval  
else left(interval,charindex(':',interval,4)-1) end from tab1
```

Comment: `interval` is just a column name

Comment: Didn't see that (as `interval` is a keyword). But still: there is no function `charindex`

Comment: I didn't see the postgreSQL.

Comment: There is also no charindex function in standard SQL to which the `sql` tag refers to.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).